# getAttribute from each <li> with pure Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, ecmascript-6

I am trying to get the value of each list items data- with pure JS.

```js
const meetTheTeamSectionNames = document.querySelectorAll('.team__names li');

Array.from(meetTheTeamSectionNames).forEach(name => {
  name.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    const nameMe = e.target.getAttribute('name')
    console.log(nameMe);
  });
});
```

```html
<ul class="team__names">
  <li class="current" data-name="neil">Neil Tully MW</li>
  <li data-name="kevin">Kevin Rylands</li>
  <li data-name="jane">Jane Coggins</li>
  <li data-name="ben">Ben Green</li>
</ul>
```

For some reason each click returns null... and I have no idea why.
Any help would be awesome :)

Comment: It's "data-name", not "name"

Comment: `getAttribute('name')` — That isn't the name of your attribute!

Comment: `li` elements are not designed to be interactive controls. Screen readers won't list them as things the user can interact with. Pressing tab to loop through the interactive elements on the page will skip them. Put `<button>` elements inside your list items and click on those instead.\

Comment: oh man.....sorry guys that was a real obvious one, should of picked up on it :S

Comment: Also good suggestion Quentin, makes total sense

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just replace

```
const nameMe = e.target.getAttribute('name')
```

with

```
const nameMe = e.target.getAttribute('data-name')
```

Perhaps you confused with `jQuery` because there we have two posibilities to get **value**

- `$(selector).attr('data-name');`
- `$(selector).data('name');`, (if you use newer jQuery >= 1.4.3)

```js
const meetTheTeamSectionNames = document.querySelectorAll('.team__names li');
    Array.from(meetTheTeamSectionNames).forEach(name => {
        name.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
            const nameMe = e.target.getAttribute('data-name')
            console.log(nameMe);
        });
    });
```

```html
<ul class="team__names">
    <li class="current" data-name="neil">Neil Tully MW</li>
    <li data-name="kevin">Kevin Rylands</li>
    <li data-name="jane">Jane Coggins</li>
    <li data-name="ben">Ben Green</li>
</ul>
```